# NodeJS Sqlite db.each is not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Code is this

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

let db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.db');

db.serialize(() => {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (username text, password text, level text);");
    db.run("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects USING FTS4(projeYili,projeAdi,ogretmenler,ogrenciler,ozet,basvurular,sonuclar,oduller);");
});


function read_projects_json(){
    let table_data_json = [];
    let sql = "SELECT rowid,* FROM projects";
    db.each(sql, (err,row) => {
        table_data_json.push({
            'id':row.rowid,
            'proje_yili':row.proje_yili,
            'proje_ogretmeni':row.proje_ogretmeni,
            'proje_ogrenciler':row.proje_ogrenciler,
            'proje_ozeti':row.proje_ozeti,
            'proje_basvurulari':row.proje_basvurulari,
            'proje_sonuclari':row.proje_sonuclari,
            'proje_alinan_oduller':row.proje_alinan_oduller
        });
    });
    return table_data_json;
}


console.log(read_projects_json());

db.close();
```

When i run this it gives [] empty array

in function read_projects_json it runs

```js
let table_data_json = [];
let sql = "SELECT rowid,* FROM projects";
```

table_data_json is Empty Array now but after that i think it not waits for db.each to finish 
and returns table_data_json as an empty array 
how can i fix that?

Comment: Try wrapping the `db.each` call in `db.serialize`.

Comment: @ChrisG if i wrap just `db.each` it still returns empty array if i wrap `db.each` with `return table_data_json;` it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I just used promises and db.all instead off db.each so i wrapped db.all in Promise

```js
function read_projects_json(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let table_data_json = [];
    let sql = "SELECT rowid,* FROM projects";
    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            table_data_json.push({
                'id':row.rowid,
                'proje_yili':row.proje_yili,
                'proje_ogretmeni':row.proje_ogretmeni,
                'proje_ogrenciler':row.proje_ogrenciler,
                'proje_ozeti':row.proje_ozeti,
                'proje_basvurulari':row.proje_basvurulari,
                'proje_sonuclari':row.proje_sonuclari,
                'proje_alinan_oduller':row.proje_alinan_oduller
            });
        });
        resolve(table_data_json);
      });
    });
}
```

after that i used then to print data

```js
read_projects_json().then((data) => console.log(data));
```